# ASP.NET MVC Call Extension Method in VB.NET Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razorengine

How to call Extension method in VB.NET Razor view. It is working in c# but not able to run it in VB.NET.

Note: Target Framework in .NET 4.0

Here is the Code:

```
@Imports ApplicationSupport.Models
    @Html.RenderXml("XML String here", Server.MapPath("~/XSLT/Contents.xslt"))
```

And then Extension Method as below:

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Mvc
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Xsl
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Namespace ApplicationSupport.Models

 Public Module HtmlHelperExtensions
        <Extension()> _
        Public Function RenderXml(helper As HtmlHelper, xml As String, xsltPath As String) As HtmlString
            Dim args As New XsltArgumentList()
            Dim t As New XslCompiledTransform()
            t.Load(xsltPath)
            Dim settings As New XmlReaderSettings()
            settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse
            settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD
            Using reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(New StringReader(xml), settings)
                Dim writer As New StringWriter()
                t.Transform(reader, args, writer)
                Dim htmlString As New HtmlString(writer.ToString())
                Return htmlString
            End Using
        End Function
    End Module
End Namespace
```

And then getting error as below:
[image: Error]

I was not able to find any useful help on it. I hope someone can point me in right direction.

I am c# programmer but this piece of code needed in VB.NET.

Answer (score 2):

I think your import in the view needs to be

```
@Imports ApplicationSupport.Models.HtmlHelperExtensions
```

so it will import the module your extension method resides in.